# Laravel vue show old data on update fields

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I've made update function for my component and it's working perfectly the only issue is I cannot show old data (if there is any) to the user,

This is what I have now:

[image: one]

As you see not only i can send my form data to back-end for update, but also I have the saved data already.

## Code

```
export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                info: '',  //getting data from database
                profile: {  //sending new data to back-end
                    photo: '',
                    about: '',
                    website: '',
                    phone: '',
                    state: '',
                    city: '',
                    user_id: '',
                    csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                }
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('testApp.jwt') != null;
            this.getInfo();
        },
        beforeMount(){
            if (localStorage.getItem('testApp.jwt') != null) {
                this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testApp.user'))
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('testApp.jwt');
                console.log()
            }
        },
         methods: {
            update() { // sending data to back-end
                let user_id = this.user.id;
                let photo = this.profile.photo;
                let about = this.profile.about;
                let website = this.profile.website;
                let phone = this.profile.phone;
                let state = this.profile.state;
                let city = this.profile.city;
                axios.put('/api/updateprofile/'+ user_id, {user_id, photo, about, website, phone, state, city}).then((response) => {
                    this.$router.push('/profile');
                    $(".msg").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your profile updated successfully.</div>').delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
                });
                Vue.nextTick(function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                })
            },
            getInfo: function() { //getting current data from database
                let user_id = this.user.id;
                axios.get('/api/show/'+ user_id).then((response) => {
                    this.info = response.data;
                    console.log(response);
                });
            },
           }
    }
```

`Component sample field`

```
// this shows my about column from database
{{info.about}}

// this sends new data to replace about column
<textarea name="about" id="about" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" v-model="profile.about" placeholder="Tentang saya..."></textarea>
```

## Question

1. How to pass old data to my fields (sample above)?

## Update

`Please open image in big size.`

[image: two]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by assigning `this.profile` the value of `this.info` on your Ajax response.
This way you will have input fields set up with original values.

```js
function callMe() {
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
     profile:{},
     info:{}
    },
    
    methods: {
    getInfo: function() { //getting current data from database
    this.info={about:"old data"}//your response here
    this.profile=Object.assign({},this.info);
          
        },
    },
   
    
  })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <button @click="getInfo">Ajax Call click me</button>
  Input <input v-model="profile.about"/>
  
  <p>profile:{{this.profile}}</p>
  <p>info: {{this.info}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't catch your solution, would you mind give sample base on my codes? (I don't have any create/watch etc.)

Comment: Check it, assume button click is ajax call.

Comment: I assume you want to show input fields with previous data initially but also want to keep info as it is. While keeping profile object in as v-model?

Comment: yes and no, see i have `text-area` field named `about` which is column in my table, so user has put some info about him/her(self) there before `this is old value` now i want show that `old value` and let them to edit it or completely remove/change it.

Comment: anyway I'm getting `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "change": got null` with this new changes

Comment: From pic, Do you want old data to be seen on right initially? but when user updates it what happens.

Comment: In my example , thats what is happening. info is kept as it is, while `profile.about` can be changed

Comment: it will show old data but as i said i also get error of `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "change": got undefined`

Comment: You just had to add this line `this.profile=Object.assign({},this.info);` after `this.info=response.data` 
Also in data()  change info:'' to info:{}

Comment: that's what I did exactly error `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "change": got null`

Comment: PS: `on-change` coming from my image field  `<input type="file" name="photo" v-on:change="profile.photo" id="photo" class="custom-file-input">`

Comment: @change needs a function . You are passing profile.photo which is a variable hence might be  the error. Remove it and check

Comment: is it possible i just use `v-model` for image field? (i'm asking this because every article i read about vue or they used @change or v-on:change)

Comment: if profile.photo is a string then yes just use v-model

Comment: `$table->string('photo')->nullable();` but when i used `v-model` my page stopped rendering (i just got white page)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178306/discussion-between-helping-hand-and-mafortis  come here

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that after assigning new value info is not reactive anymore. You need to keep "info" like this in the start.

```
info: {  // data from api
                photo: '',
                about: '',
                website: '',
                phone: '',
                state: '',
                city: '',
                user_id: '',
       }
```

And after fetching values from api update each value separately.

```
getInfo: function() { //getting current data from database
            let user_id = this.user.id;
            axios.get('/api/show/'+ user_id).then((response) => {
                this.info.photo = response.data.photo;
                this.info.about = response.data.about;
                //all other values
                console.log(response);
            });
        },
```

Comment: so i did what you suggested but nothing shows in my fields.

Comment: In the start assign initial random values to info fields and check when component load whether it is displaying those values.

Answer (score 0):

In your textarea you have a model `profile.about`, the way to show the "old data", is to assing to that model the data

in the `create` or `mounted` method you have to assing like

```
this.profile.about = this.info.about
```

this way `profile.about` will have the data stored in your db, that way if the user update it, the old data will be keep safe in `this.info.about` and the edited in `this.profile.about`

Comment: I want to show old data in text/teatarea fields so user can see their current data and if they want change it.

Comment: i still do not understand, wich is your old data, the one you send in the update function? and the textarea where it is? is in the same view where you update or in the profile route?

Comment: what i want is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919569/laravel-vue-show-old-data-on-update-fields#comment90789466_51919730  / text area is in my code in question above. all in 1 view as their function is together in 1 method